# Exposing multiple ports/Express apps on Amazon Lambda

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

Is it possible to expose multiple Express apps under different ports on Amazon Lambda? Let's assume the following structure in my local setup:

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')

const app = express()
const app2 = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Hello from App!\n');
})

app2.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Hello from The Second App!\n');
})

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
http.createServer(app2).listen(4000);
```

Then, when preparing that for lambda I need a handler function, which would probably make the file end like this:

```
[...]
//http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
//http.createServer(app2).listen(4000);

const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app, null, binaryMimeTypes);
exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context)
```

I may not be the typical use case, but I already have a project that consists of multiple apps under different ports and a websocket server. I would want to move it to Lambda. So in the end to access the server with:

```
<url_api_gateway>.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:3000
<url_api_gateway>.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:4000
```

Is there any way to expose each port separately on Lambda with the help of API Gateway and CloudFormation? Also, would it be possible to expose a range of ports, as there's a scenario to assign ports dynamically?

If that's not possible is there a way to make a port to url mapping, e.g.:

```
<url_api_gateway>.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app1 --> PORT 3000
<url_api_gateway>.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app2 --> PORT 4000
```

Just to be more clear, app2 is a HTTP Proxy server that is impossible to integrate within app. Thanks in advance.